Is there an equivalent to textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar in Jetpack Compose Material3?
In my Jetpack Compose project using Material3, I'm looking for a way to add a toolbar directly above the keyboard, similar to how textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar works in iOS/Swift.
I want this toolbar to appear automatically when the TextField is focused, allowing users easy access to additional actions (like navigation buttons or submit actions) without hiding the keyboard.
I've explored options like Modifier.imePadding() and placing a BottomAppBar, but they don’t fully replicate the inputAccessoryView functionality where the toolbar is directly connected to the keyboard and follows it.
Is there a way to achieve this in Jetpack Compose, or are there any workarounds to implement a keyboard-attached toolbar effectively?
